# Build doctrine association between Entity and Association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations

I have three doctrine entities that I would like to associate:

Document, AttributeKeys, AttributeValues

AttributeValues has a manyToMany association with AttributeValues. So one attribute key can have several possible values, but one value can also be assigned to different keys. I now want, that the Document takes a combination of AttributeKey and AttributeValue.

For example:

```
AttributeKey
1 from
2 to
3 vehicle

AttributeValue
1 Berlin (manyToMany with key 1 and 2)
2 Rom  (manyToMany with key 1 and 2)
3 Paris (manyToMany with key 1 and 2)
4 Car (manyToMany with key 3)
5 Ship (manyToMany with key 3)

Document
1 Application (association with Key1+Value2 and Key3+Value4)
2 Nomination (association with Key1+Value3 and Key3+Value5)
```

So the association between AttributeKey and AttributeValue is no problem and already exists. 
But I now want to make a new association between Document and the manyToMany association of key+value So I try to make not an Entity<->Entity association but an Entity<->Association association

Comment: Have you already read the nicely written chapter 5 of the Doctrine documentation ? Or you expect someone to build the entities mapping in stackoverflow :) http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: of yourse I did :) I might have not explicit enough, I only need to know, how I can make an association between the document and a combination (association?) of the attribute entities. I already did the manyToMany association between AttributeKey+AttributeValue. That is not a problem of course. But now I need to associate this association with a third entity (Document). I update the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok I (hopefully) solved the problem myself:

I created a new Entity `AttributeKeyValue` that takes the manyToMany association between Key+Value with two oneToMany associations. Then I made a new `manyToMany` between `Document` and `AttributeKeyValue`

```
AppBundle\Entity\AttributeKeyValue:
type: entity
table: attribute_keys_values
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AttributeKeyValueRepository
manyToOne:
    attributeKey:
        targetEntity: AttributeKey
    attributeValue:
        targetEntity: AttributeValue
manyToMany:
    documents:
      targetEntity: Document
      mappedBy: attributes    
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
```

And in Entity/Document:

```
manyToMany:
   attributes:
      targetEntity: AttributeKeyValue
      inversedBy: documents
      joinTable:
          name: documents_attributes
```